# Improving drumstick control in non-dominant hand

Tags: technique, drums

Why is it that my drumstick in my dominant hand always hits the same spot yet the drumstick in my non-dominant rarely does?

Comment: I guess it would be a good idea to provide information at least about which grip you play?

Comment: Thank you for replying. As a left-handed player, my left is mostly french grip with a touch of matched grip, however, my right hand is the opposite (mostly match with a touch of french. I have been practicing paradiddles using all wrist movement, at about 50bpm with the emphasise of hitting within the same vacinity (30-40mm radius). Incredibly frustrating!!!  The left is spot on.

Comment: As a matter of interest, have you set up your kit right - handed, like most of the kits you'll encounter?. Not sure what French grip is, I guess palm up. That would mean you're actually playing right-handed. The problem may be you're using too much arm movement in your playing.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly due to the dominant hand/wrist/arm having years of practice being pretty accurate , whereas the non-dominant one/s have been lazy!

If you had used both equally in all sorts of tasks - throwing a ball, punching, picking up, prodding, swiping, the list goes on, then they'd be about equal, and you'd be fairly ambidextrous. Which is a good thing for a drummer.

Even with matched grip, that non-dominant limb needs to catch up on the years of practice its partner has over it. Try to favour it more - after all, the dominant one can pretty well cope.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it is a good reminder to use my right hand more frequently. I have fallen out of that pattern but will alter that now, infact, I will see if I can pour a beer with my right hand without spilling any!!! :  )